# How to skip download jar when open maven project in IDEA?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Sometimes I just want to see a small piece of code in a maven project. Every time I open a maven project, I need to download the jar defined in pom.xml. I can't see the source code without downloading it. What should I do?

Comment: How long does it take?

Comment: About a minutes to a few minutes.mostly less than 5 minutes

Comment: It is strange that it takes so long. Maybe a firewall or a virus scan slows it down. (Sorry, I cannot answer your original request, but hopefully someone else will).

Comment: 23333,because I was in China,this network was sooooo slow